# Partial sum of the reciprocal of the primes squared

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

It is known that the sum of the reciprocal of the primes squared converge to $0.4522\cdots$. Here my question is: is

$$\sum_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{p>N}{p\text{ is prime}}}\frac1{p^2}<\frac1N$$

hold for every positive integers $N$? I will be appreciated for any useful comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{p>N}{p\text{ is prime}}}\frac1{p^2}
<\sum_{k>N} \frac1{k(k-1)}= \sum_{k>N} \Bigl(\frac1{ k-1 }-\frac1k\Bigr)=\frac1N \,.$$

Comment: I dunno, the first one assumes that not every number larger than N is a prime.  :)

Comment: @Yakk No, for $k>N\ge1$ there is $1/k<1/(k-1)$